# Vim: Searching for class/func-view Plugin

Tags: vim

iam searching a VIM Plugin for a Overview from all classes and funcs in a file. You can see this on the right site here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQy2rVOf-z0

Does anyone know whats the name of this plugin?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin is called [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My answer is the exact answer to the question. The name of the plugin and a link to the plugin's page on sourceforge. The asker already knows what the plugin does, he only needed a name. Your concerns would be valid if it was a link to a snippet or a tutorial or a documentation page but it's a link to a sourceforge project so that principle doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite one is [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/). Screenshots are included in the provided link.

> Tagbar is a vim plugin for browsing the tags of source code files. It
>   provides a sidebar that displays the ctags-generated tags of the
>   current file, ordered by their scope. This means that for example
>   methods in C++ are displayed under the class they are defined in.

If you are using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) you can install it by adding the following to your vimrc

```
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
```